# C++ Modeling a dynamic board of objects

Tags: c++

I am designing a C++ console program that models a board of `Shapes`. The only rule is that all `Shapes` that are placed on the board have to be added to an existing `Line` (with the exception of the first move). Whenever a `Shape` is placed on the board, it has a `Line` in both the horizontal and vertical direction, even if it is the only member of the line.

I have implemented the `Line` and `Shape` objects fine. The issue I am struggling with is how to organize the lines. It didn't seem like a good idea to give the line a position (as in a x,y coordinate), because the board is dynamic and can expand in any direction. Right now each line only has a direction, vertical or horizontal. I also need to be able to print the board to the console, so the user can indicate where they want to add on.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to model this situation efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what the rules are, but if you're concerned about a freely expanding grid, you could consider storing the `Shape` objects in a map:

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> TGridPos;
typedef std::map<TGridPos,Shape> TGrid;
```

Perhaps you could elaborate more on the gameplay.

Comment: Specifically is there anything you want me to expand? In a more general way, the game works by placing these shapes, they have to connect to a line. The reason I didn't do something like that was it got really messy dealing with a coordinate system that was constantly changing. I thought it might make sense to do something like only comparing the positions of the lines relative to each other. Then when a user wants to add a shape, they can specify exactly which line they want to add it to. Is that too complicated?

Comment: I was just confused about exactly where a shape is placed and whether it already has lines or if you place single lines.  The thing is, the coordinate system doesn't change.  It can go negative - that's fine.  In terms of displaying, you just keep track of the TGridPos of the top-left point on the screen - same way that scrollbars work.  The only inefficiency in this approach is the actual display (but it might be minor - you just search for all grid points that will be visible in the current viewport defined by top-left and width-height).  Finding individual points is fast.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear about that. Every tile has to be added to an existing line. Last time I tried the same kind of thing, I added the shape to a map, then I had to iterate through all the possible lines and try to add the shape. The updating the lines became the most expensive function in the whole program because every tile had to be individually added to the lines. Also, I didn't mention it before, but this program uses a brute-force technique, so it tries out hundreds of different shape placements. So the adding shapes to the board needs to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: I thought that removing the whole idea of adding the shape to the grid, then updating the lines would make it run more efficiently. Maybe I just need a more efficient way to update the lines. The biggest issue arose like this (assuming X is new shape, Y is existing): XXYYYY The only way I could think to do it was try adding the farthest left new tile, then if it couldn't add (which in this case it can't), moving on to the next new shape, which can add. But then I need to go back and add the original shape. It was a nightmare.

Comment: I know what would REALLY help - a picture of what a board looks like after a few moves, with the possible locations for a new shape highlighted (as well as a picture showing all the possible shape tiles)

Answer (score 0):

Allow negative positions in x and y.  This will allow the board to expand equally in all directions (except that the number of integral values positive aand negative are off by one) without requiring coordinate changes.

Your issue is how to display it.  If you store the min and max x and y indices, you would use a for loop like

```
for(int x = minX; x <= maxX; ++x) {
    for(int y = minY; y <= maxY; ++y) {
        // display at x,y
    }
}
```

Instead of from x=0 and y=0 which are common.  This is clear, avoids changing any notion of index values with expansion of the board, and lets you use indexes.